# problems with javafx canvas.setOnKeyPress() detecting keys

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to create a snake game in javafx using canvas and set up onkeypressed on it and noticed that if i press UP arrow the RIGHT arrow cant be detected and sometimes when i press LEFT arrow the DOWN arrow doesnt get detected. The keys work in random sequences but if i press left then up the right key dont work

Here is the part where i set up the keys (they dont do anything other than print on console):

```
        canvas.requestFocus();
        canvas.setFocusTraversable(true);
        canvas.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                switch (keyEvent.getCode())
                {
                    case UP:
                    case DOWN:
                    case LEFT:
                    case RIGHT:
                        System.out.println(keyEvent.getCode()); break;
                }
            }
        });
```

Here is the entire class:

```
public class GUI extends Application{
    private static Text scoreText;
    private static Canvas canvas;
    private int width = 600, height = 400;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        // holder for canvas
        StackPane holder = new StackPane(addCanvas());
        holder.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#3d494a");
        //add the layouts to the borderpane
        borderPane.setTop(addAnchorPane());
        borderPane.setCenter(holder);
        //the scene
        Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane, width, height);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("/res/style.css");
        //set the stage
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
        stage.setTitle("Snake");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        //draws the initial snake at the centre
        new Thread(new SnakeDraw()).start();
        new Thread(new FruitDraw()).start();
        stage.show();
    }

    public AnchorPane addAnchorPane() {
        AnchorPane anchorpane = new AnchorPane();
        anchorpane.setId("anchorpane");
        anchorpane.getStyleClass().add("anchorpane");

        //reset Button
        Button buttonReset = new Button("reset");
        buttonReset.setStyle("-fx-font: 22 arial; -fx-base: #b6e7c9;");
        buttonReset.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                Main.setScore(0);
                GUI.scoreText.setText(String.format("Score: %d", Main.getScore()));
                canvas.getGraphicsContext2D().clearRect(0,0,1000, 1000);
                Main.resetSnake();
                new Thread(new SnakeDraw()).start();
                new Thread(new FruitDraw()).start();
            }
        });

        //Quit Button
        Button buttonQuit = new Button("Quit");
        buttonQuit.setStyle("-fx-font: 22 arial; -fx-base: #b6e7c9;");
        buttonQuit.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        scoreText = new Text(10, 10, String.format("Score: %d", Main.getScore()));
        scoreText.setFont(Font.font("arial", 34));
        HBox scoreBox = new HBox(scoreText);
        HBox hb = new HBox();
        hb.setPadding(new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2));
        hb.setSpacing(10);
        hb.getChildren().addAll(buttonReset, buttonQuit);

        anchorpane.getChildren().addAll(scoreBox, hb);
        AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(hb, 8.0);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(hb, 5.0);

        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(scoreBox, 5.0);
        AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(scoreBox, 8.0);
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(scoreBox, 4.0);

        return anchorpane;
    }

    public Canvas addCanvas() {
        canvas = new Canvas(600,400);
        return canvas;
    }

    public static Canvas getCanvas() {
        //Button mapping
        canvas.requestFocus();
        canvas.setFocusTraversable(true);
        canvas.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                switch (keyEvent.getCode())
                {
                    case UP:
                    case DOWN:
                    case LEFT:
                    case RIGHT:
                    default: System.out.println(keyEvent.getCode()); break;
                }
            }
        });
        return canvas;
    }
}
```

Also the GraphicsContext of the canvas get called from 2 threads to draw objects onto the canvas:

```
public class SnakeDraw implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        GraphicsContext gc = GUI.getCanvas().getGraphicsContext2D();
        for (int i = 0; i < Main.getSnakeBlocksSize(); i++) {
            SnakeBlock snakeBlock = Main.getSnakeBlock(i);
            System.out.println(snakeBlock);
            gc.setFill(Color.BLACK);
            gc.fillRect(snakeBlock.getX(), snakeBlock.getY(), snakeBlock.getSizex(), snakeBlock.getSizey());
            System.out.println("Created a snake at: " + snakeBlock.getX() + ", " + snakeBlock.getY());
        }
    }
}
```

I tried WASD and any other keys and they all seem fine. It's only the arrow keys that are showing this problem, could it be my keyboard thats faulty or something in my code?

Comment: Not 100% sure if the issue you describe is actually the same, since the description is not clear on whether you want parallel key presses to be triggered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23052257/multiple-key-press-on-javafx-scene Furthermore note that there's no guarantee that javafx will trigger key events repeatedly, if you keep a key pressed. BTW: modifying the GUI from a background thread will get you into trouble sooner or later. You probably created yourself a bug that is hard to reproduce...

Comment: I do not press them simultaneously, I wait for the console to detect key is pressed to press the other one. Also true about the thread i get an illegalthreadexpression and i looked it up and found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41274078/graphics-context-will-only-draw-in-one-thread

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56502206/trying-to-make-the-shape-continuously-move-in-one-direction-with-arrow-keys/56503657#56503657

Comment: that looks way better approach than mine, tried it and it works. I guess ill ditch the Canvas in my code for Pane